# How to fix the height issues in chrome using css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

the height of the wrapper div looks expanded on chrome browser. however looks good on the safari browser.

below is my code,

```
function View() {
    return (
        <Wrapper>
            <LeftWrapper>
                <ContentBox height={30}>
                    <Overview>
                </ContentBox>
                <ContentBox height={70}>
                    <Items>
                </ContentBox>
            </LeftWrapper>
            <RightWrapper>
                <ContentBox>
                    <Products/>
                </ContentBox>
            </RightWrapper>
        </Wrapper>
    );
}



const Wrapper = styled(LoadingTemplate)`
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 1200px;
    height: 500px;
    min-height: 500px;
    max-height: 90vh;
    max-width: 90vw;
    flex: 1;
`;

 const LeftWrapper = styled.div`
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     height: 100%;
 `;

  const RightWrapper = styled.div`
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      height: 100%;
  `;

   const ContentBox = styled.div<{ height: number }>`;
       height: calc(${props => props.height}% - ${boxSpacing}px);
   `;


    function Products(s) {
        return (
            <>
                <span>Products</span>
                <span>something</span>

                <ProductList products={products} />
            </>
        );
    }

    function ProductsList() {

        return (
            <>
                <Table>
                    <TableHeaderRow>
                        <TableHeader>
                            Name
                            <SortCaret/>
                        </TableHeader>
                        <TableHeader>header</TableHeader>
                        <TableHeader>
                            first
                            <SortCaret/>
                        </TableHeader>
                        <TableHeader>
                            header 1
                            <SortCaret/>
                        </TableHeader>
                    </TableHeaderRow>
                    <TableRowsWrapper>
                        {products.map(p => (
                            <Fragment key={p.id}>
                                <ExpandableRow/>
                                {expandedSite === site.id && (
                                    <ExpandedRow/>
                                )}
                            </Fragment>
                        ))}
                    </TableRowsWrapper>
                </Table>
                <ButtonWrapper>
                    <Button>
                        Click
                    </Button>
                </ButtonWrapper>
            </>
       );
   }

   const Table = styled.div`
       width: 100%;
       height: calc(100% - 102px);
       display: flex;
       flex-direction: column;
   `;

    const TableRowsWrapper = styled.div`
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        height: calc(100% - 50px);
        overflow-y: auto;
    `;
```

I am not sure where the problem is. removing height on Wrapper sets the height of LeftWrapper fine (doesnt look stretched on chrome) but it adds vertical scrollbar to the page and height of RightWrapper is still the same meaning fits to the page completely and goes beyond the view.

could someone help me fix this? thanks.

**EDIT:**

i have tried the below,

in wrapper i have removed height, min-height and max-height and set height: 61vh to the RightWrapper. this works.

but when there is no content inside the rightwrapper this looks slightly bigger than the leftwrapper. both left and right wrappers should be of same height.

how can i fix this? thanks

Comment: Could you please remove that reactjs-code and show the effective result (plain html/css)?

Comment: I generally use https://autoprefixer.github.io/ for making css work in different browsers, it automatically adds the prefixes required for safari, chrome, mozilla on different properties. Give it a try this might fix the issue

Comment: Also add a screenshot of safari view as well as chrome view

Comment: i have edited my question to what i have tried.